# render HTML based on REST API permissions

Tags: javascript, html, rest, api, vue.js

I have a clientside rendered frontend with a REST API. The frontend should render some elements based on the user authorization. Example permissions could be

- delete users
- being able to delete supervisors too
- create users
- add users to workflows
- ...

A huge amount of permissions is managed by an administrator. My question is:

**How would you get to know what permissions you have for this rendered page and what to render?**

The only idea that comes to my mind would be to create an API endpoint `/user/:id/permissions` and ask for every permission the user has. An example response object could be

```
[
  {
    "permissionId": 0,
    "description": "Has access to page"
  },
  {
    "permissionId": 1,
    "description": "Can create users"
  },
  {
    "permissionId": 2,
    "description": "Can delete users"
  }
  // ...
]
```

Then I could start rendering my HTML based on these permissions (Pseudo code / I normally use VueJs)

```
<button render-if="permissions.contains(1)">This shows up if the user can create users</button>
<button render-if="permissions.contains(2)">This shows up if the user can delete other users</button>
```

I think the frontend code might get a bit messy. The API endpoint should be fine but maybe there is a better solution. Does a best practise solution already exist?

Comment: You must check user credentials so you can fetch permissions with user instead of doing extra request for something that is related anyway. If there are few UI elements handled by permissions, its ok to do it conditionally. If UI differences becomes too complex, its better to split it into user and admin view. To make permissions more clean, you can add enum sid column. Like delete_user, delete_all, create_user, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach (having a separate permissions endpoint) is a good way to handle this.

Another alternative is to use a hypermedia format like HAL or Siren. Whenever you access *any* resource, that resource will include a list of links with information about what the user might want to do next. If a link doesn't appear in a response, the implication is that the user can't perform that action (due to permission issues or otherwise).